# Uncommon lexical aspects

Tags: aspect, aktionsart

In Q’eqchi’ you can derive verbs with different lexical aspects from a base verb, e.g:

Verbal stem b’ak’

(0) xinb’ak’ = I tied it

(1) xinb’ak’b’ak’i = I tied it quickly

(2) xinb’ak’le = I tied it various times

(3) xinb’ak’b’e = I tied it quickly various times (combination of 1 and 2)

(4) xinb’ak’axiheb’ = I tied them separatly. For instance: Xinb’ak’eb’ li tz’i’. = Ich tied the dogs (together). Xinb’ak’axiheb’ li tz’i’. I tied each dog separately (to a pole).

(5) b’ak’aamilin = I was tied suddenly or unexpectedly.

Are there established words for these lexical aspects?
How do you call it when something happens (1) quickly, (2) repeatedly, (5) suddenly and (4) separately to various objects?

Is (4) even a lexical aspect?

I think (2) might be called "frequentative" (verbum frequentativum), however I am not sure about this and I don't have a clue how one could call the other examples.

Comment: What makes you think these are aspectual suffixes and not simply postclitic adverbs?

Comment: @fdb For instance (1) is formed by reduplication so I don't think this can be a clitic adverb. Also those morphemes never show up anywhere else as adverbials. But no matter whether they be adverbs or not, they add aspectual information to the verbal stem. How could one concisely call those derived forms.

Comment: 4) seems more like an expression of distributive plurality than an aspect.

Comment: The terms are punctive and iterative.